# How to bind bootstrap button-checkbox and form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

There is a code look like this:

```
<form action="/test.html" method="get">
    <p><b>Question?</b></p>
    <p><input type="radio" name="answer" value="a">C<Br>
       <input type="radio" name="answer" value="b">B<Br>
       <input type="radio" name="answer" value="c">C</p>

    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-checkbox">
    <button type="button" name="bb" value="b1" class="btn btn-primary">Left</button>
    <button type="button" name="bb" value="b2" class="btn btn-primary">Middle</button>
    <button type="button" name="bb" value="b3" class="btn btn-primary">Right</button>
    </div>

    <p><input type="submit"></p>
</form>
```

How to send it to the get method? Probably have to write some js(jquery) code, but I can't come up anything.

Comment: Your code is already submitting to the `/test.html` page: `<form action="/test.html" method="get">`

Comment: **sushain97** but data from `buttons-checkbox` don't sending, about this issue.

Comment: **Dipesh Parmar** I tried the $.get(), but for some reason it did not work. Besides would have to write code for the standard input fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you've got is that button values are not submitted.

The following will create hidden input elements for the buttons that are selected as the form is submitted.

```
<form action="/test.html" id="the-form" method="get">
    <p><b>Question?</b></p>
    <p><input type="radio" name="answer" value="a">C<Br>
       <input type="radio" name="answer" value="b">B<Br>
       <input type="radio" name="answer" value="c">C</p>

    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-checkbox">
        <button type="button" name="bb1" value="b1" class="btn btn-primary">Left</button>
        <button type="button" name="bb2" value="b2" class="btn btn-primary">Middle</button>
        <button type="button" name="bb3" value="b3" class="btn btn-primary">Right</button>
    </div>

    <p><input type="submit"></p>
</form>
<script>
    $('#the-form').on('submit', function() {
        $('.btn.active', '#the-form').each(function() {
            var input = document.createElement("input");
            input.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
            input.setAttribute("name", this.name);
            input.setAttribute("value", this.value);
            document.getElementById("the-form").appendChild(input);
        });
    });
</script>
```

N.B. In order for this to work I had to give the form an id, and give the buttons unique names (as they're `buttons-checkbox` rather than `buttons-radio`, see [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#buttons)).

If you want `buttons-group` behaviour use:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
    <button type="button" name="bb" value="b1" class="btn btn-primary">Left</button>
    <button type="button" name="bb" value="b2" class="btn btn-primary">Middle</button>
    <button type="button" name="bb" value="b3" class="btn btn-primary">Right</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your buttons under `.btn-group` are not submitting because they are of the incorrect type. You need to change `type="button"` to `type="submit"`. Only buttons which have `type="submit"` will submit the parent `form` (default button type is `submit`)).

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-checkbox">
    <button type="submit" name="bb" value="b1" class="btn btn-primary">Left</button>
    <button type="submit" name="bb" value="b2" class="btn btn-primary">Middle</button>
    <button type="submit" name="bb" value="b3" class="btn btn-primary">Right</button>
</div>
```